# Prove that the triangle $ABC$ is a right triangle

Tags: geometry

Prove that the triangle with points $$A(a,b), B(c,d), C\left(h, d-\left(\frac{c-a}{d-b}\right)h+\left(\frac{c-a}{d-b}\right)c\right)$$

its sides comply with the Pythagorean theorem

I have not been able to show it,
some clue?

Answer (score 1):

We know that $A(a,b)$ and $B(c,d)$ do not form the hypotenuse as $C$ already has the x-coordinate $h$.

Assuming $AC$ to be the hypotenuse, products of slopes of $AB$ and $BC$ should be $-1$ for our assumption to be true.

Slope of $BC$ = $\frac{\frac{c-a}{d-b}\cdot{h-c}}{c-h}$

Slope of $AB$ = $\frac{d-b}{c-a}$

Slope of $AB$ $\cdot$ Slope of $BC$ = $-1$

Hence our assumption was true, and $ABC$ forms a right angled triangle with hypotenuse $AC$.